# Catch block isn't executed in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling

I have a stored procedure that should delete a schema from the database. I execute this stored procedure from the backend (using C#). As the result, I want to receive boolean value if deleting is successful or not.

```
var result = await session.Sp<bool>(c => c.spDeleteSchemaTotally, new { schemaName})
                                         .SingleAsync()
                                         .ConfigureAwait(false);

if (result)
{
     tracer.Info("Deleted successfully");
}
else
{
     tracer.Warn("Schema was not deleted appropriately");
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDeleteSchemaTotally]
    (@schemaName NVARCHAR(100))
AS
    SET FMTONLY OFF
BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE SchemaList
    SET [Status] = 2 /* DELETING */
    WHERE SchemaName = @schemaName

    EXEC [dbo].[spDeleteSchema] @schemaName

    EXEC [dbo].[spDeleteSchemaOwner] @schemaName

    EXEC [dbo].[spDeleteSchemaUserRoles] @schemaName

    UPDATE SchemaList
    SET [Status] = 1 /* DELETED */,
        SchemaName = SchemaName + '|deleted|' + FORMAT(GETUTCDATE(), 'MM-d-yyyy-hh:mm')
    WHERE SchemaName = @schemaName

    SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    UPDATE SchemaList
    SET [Status] = 3 /* ERRORED */
    WHERE SchemaName = @schemaName

    SELECT CAST(0 AS BIT);
END CATCH
```

I have a table, where I store a list of all schemas. For each schema, I have some status. Each schema has some own tables, rules etc.

But for some reasons, I have noticed that some error happens (sometimes) and schema is left with status 2 (deleting). What kind of error - I don't know, because cannot catch this moment.

Logically to think, some error happens inside stored procedures, but for that, I have catch block. According to [this topic](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) error inside some inner stored procedure should be handled by outer catch. So I think everything written in the correct way... but not correct behavior still exists.

Can somebody point me into the correct way of handling errors in above stored procedure?

I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: How do you know that an error is occurring without triggering the CATCH block?   Can you provide a script that others can run that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: @TabAlleman, it is hard to reproduce this "error" or my assumption of "error". Have tried this manually - but without luck.

Comment: I BELIEVE you need to have the catch blocks within each separate sp that is called.  An error within the stored proc is out of the scope of the calling SQL, if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you share the code for those other procedures? Do they have try/squelch blocks  also? The problem you have with your catch is that if you do catch an error you have swallowed the details. It will be incredibly painful to debug because you just update the status to 3 and don't do anything useful with error information.

Comment: Use of try/catch is no replacement for the use of a transaction to guarantee that all of the database updates are rolled back when an error occurs. Seems you need to study Erland's discussion of error handling much more thoroughly. Eating the error will make diagnosing any issues impossible.

Comment: @SeanLange, no, inside inner SPs try-catch blocks aren't present. About error_message you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your stored procedures are following this sort of framework then your error should be passed back upstream to the `CATCH` block in the top caller:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE y 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 / 0;
END;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE x
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC y;
        SELECT 0 AS result;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT error_message();
        SELECT 1 AS result;
    END CATCH;
END;
GO
EXEC x;
```

If I run this then procedure y will generate a "Divide by zero error encountered" error, which is then propagated back to procedure x, where it's handled and reported.

If you have a `TRY-CATCH` block in procedure y then this will consume the error and nothing will be sent back to procedure x.

Also, you could use `RETURN 0` or `RETURN 1` to return the success/ failure status of your stored procedure, rather than using a `SELECT` query to do this, it's just better practice.  If you had extra information to pass back, e.g. an error message, then you could use an `OUTPUT` parameter to do this.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE y 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 / 0;
END;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE x (
    @message VARCHAR(512) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC y;
        RETURN 0;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @message = error_message();
        RETURN 1;
    END CATCH;
END;
GO
DECLARE @message VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE @ret INT;
EXEC @ret = x @message OUTPUT;
SELECT @ret, @message;
```

---

Or here's an example of passing the inner exception all the way back again:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE y (
    @message VARCHAR(512) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT 1 / 0;
        RETURN 0;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @message = 'Inner ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
        RETURN 1;
    END CATCH;
END;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE x (
    @message VARCHAR(512) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @ret INT;
        EXEC @ret = y @message OUTPUT;
        RETURN @ret;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @message = 'Outer ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
        RETURN 1;
    END CATCH;
END;
GO
DECLARE @message VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE @ret INT;
EXEC @ret = x @message OUTPUT;
SELECT @ret, @message;
```

When you run that you will get a return status of 1 (exception), and the error message: "Inner Divide by zero error encountered.".  So we know this error was actually raised by the procedure y, even though procedure x reported it.

Comment: Question - is it fine to wrap in try-catch block SPs `x` and `y` and rethrow error from the inner stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, I'll add an example

Comment: Note that you could throw an exception in y, but why do this?  If you follow the chain back then we handle the error, consuming it in one procedure, then passing it back up the chain until we get back to "procedure zero".  If we did `RAISEEXCEPTION` instead, then we wouldn't have quite the same level of control.  For example, I could also pass back a context `OUTPUT` parameter, to help me with debugging in my model, in fact I could have as many parameters as I like (up to the limit).  But if I go down the exception route then I can only ever pass a single piece of information back up the chain

Answer (score 0):

If each of inner stored procedure do have Try-Catch construction you need to add THROW command to Catch blocks of each inner SPs.

It will throw an error to outer SP and you will be able to track it.

The idea is that if error occurs in inner SP with Try-Catch block the outer SP doesn't fail and doesn't know there was error.

[Throw documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[Try-Catch documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)